# Create a flickering/variable SKLightNode in SpriteKit - simulate campfire lighting

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an animated campfire using an texture atlas in SpriteKit, I am trying to simulate the variable lighting that a fire would produce. I was able to achieve a flicker by varying the falloff by passing in a random number form 0...1.5. It works but is a little too crazy - looking for a suggestion on smoothing it out to be more subtle and realistic - maybe pass an array of set values thru - not sure how I would do that? Or some sort of easing?

```
func buildCampfire() {
        let campfireAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "Campfire")
        var fireFrames: [SKTexture] = []
        
        let numImages = campfireAtlas.textureNames.count
        for i in 1...numImages {
            let fireTextureName = "campfire\(i)"
            fireFrames.append(campfireAtlas.textureNamed(fireTextureName))
        }
        animatedCampfire = fireFrames
        
        let firstFrameTexture = animatedCampfire[0]
        campfire = SKSpriteNode(texture: firstFrameTexture)
        campfire.size.height = 300
        campfire.size.width = 300
        campfire.position = CGPoint(x: 108, y: -188)
        addChild(campfire)
    }
    
    func animateCampfire() {
        campfire.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: animatedCampfire, timePerFrame: 0.1, resize: false, restore: true)), withKey: "campfireAnimated")
    }

    
    func flickerCampfire() {
        if let campfireLight = self.childNode(withName: "//campfireLight") as? SKLightNode {
            campfireLight.falloff = CGFloat.random(in: 0..<1.5)
    
        } else {
            print("cannot find light node")
        }
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        flickerCampfire()
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'animatedCampfire = fireFrames' mean?

Comment: fireFrames is a temp array to store the frames for the animation? I watched a tutorial and this was there approach - it works but does seem redundant? I am open to any suggestions to clean up this whole thing - cuz I have several animations to add in this same fashion....

Comment: Function `flickerCampfire` is being called 60 times a second (as it is in `update`), you probably want to reduce how many times it gets called. Maybe also look at randomly moving the position of `campfireLight`, only move it a small distance though.

Comment: @JohnL - Yeah I am just realizing that's node a good place for this to be called.  Im pretty green here - how would you go about randomly moving the position? and where would you call it?